# Casting int to char and back using extended ASCII range

Tags: java

I'am currently developing a Java client server game. Imagine I have a shuffled talon of cards, there are 70 cards and every card has a fixed ID (0-69);

When this talon is shuffled I have an array of int containing the IDs (example below does only contain a few possible numbers).

Now I thought it would be a good idea to "encode" this talon as a string and send that to a Client via DataOutputStream for example.

The way I'd like to do this is by casting int to char but I'm using the extended ASCII range (> 127). When I'm testing this, the chars I get are all ISO8859-1, so far so good. But recently I think I read that you cannot be absolutely sure that every JVM behaves like the same in the range >127.

My question now is: what would I have to do to be 100% sure that the Java client will get exactly the same number when casting back to int? Is it possible?

Thanks.

```
// Server side
int[] numbers = new int[] { 5, 47, 31, 30, 20, 58, 11, 5, 19 }; 
String s = "";

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  s += (char) (numbers[i] + 150);
}


//Client side
int[] decoded = new int[s.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
   decoded[i] = ((int) s.charAt(i)) - 150;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be sure that ISO-8859-1 is the same on every platform.  If you want to use `ISO-8859-1` it doesn't make much sense to convert numbers into chaacters and then use an encoding to convert it back again into numbers (bytes).  You may as well use bytes end to end.

```
byte[] numbers = { 5, 47, 31, 30, 20, 58, 11, 5, 19 }; 

OutputStream out = ...
out.write(numbers.length);
out.write(numbers);

DataInputStream in = 
byte[] bytes = new byte[in.read()];
in.readFully(bytes);
```

or you can use text.

```
PrintWriter pw = ...
pw.print(numbers.length);
for(byte b: numbers) {
    pw.print(" ");
    pw.print(b);
}
pw.println();

Scanner in = ...
byte[] b = new byte[in.nextInt()];
for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
    b[i] = in.nextInt();
```

---

If you want to send numbers, just send the numbers instead of text.  If you want text, send them as number is text.  Don't mix binary and text data as this often leads to confusion.

I don't see any value id adding 150 to numbers, you will still end up with the same problem.

BTW If you want to send the description of a randomly generated game set e.g. minecraft world or set of cards, you can just send the seed.  From the seed, you can re-create the same shuffled set of cards.

Comment: Just one more question. You said I can be sure that ISO-8859-1 is the same on every platform. What if a user uses -Dfile.encoding=... is it possible to set manually any charset value that would have the effect that the decoding would be not the same as on the server?

Comment: @N00bOverflow As the name suggests `ISO-8859-1` is an open standard, so it's encoding is defined and is the same on all platforms not just Java.  Given it is incredibly simple i.e. chars 0 to 255 are bytes 0 to 255, it is pretty hard to get wrong.  The only issue using it is the behaviour of chars > 255 is undefined, though on java they all get mapped to `?`

Comment: Concur it is clearer to send as `int` or text. But to answer as asked, if you send and receive `String` on `Data{Output,Input}Stream` it uses a Java-internal encoding and is unchanged. **What can vary is the default conversion between `String` or `char`s and `byte`s.** If you use File...Stream's or socket Stream's etc. those handle bytes. To do 8859-1 chars on them, create `OutputStreamWriter` or `InputStreamReader` with explicit charset ISO-8859-1, or explicitly convert with `String.getBytes()` and `new String(...)` specifying ISO-8859-1.